# #item not moving tabs - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how the tab system works in bootstrap.

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="tabbable-line">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#standings" data-toggle="tab">
                        Standings </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#find_match" data-toggle="tab">
                        Find Match </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#rules" data-toggle="tab">
                        Rules </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="standings">
                        <p>First Tab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="find_match">
                        <p>Second Tab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="rules">
                        <p>Third Tab</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
```

This uses anchors to navigate between the tabs, right? So how do I move to for example tab three by entering `http://url.com/#rules` ?

When I try this, it does not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap does not use href attribute to navigate the tabs. It's only refers to the ID of the div to be shown when we click on tab.
In bootstrap JS just search for   **data-toggle="tab"** and **Tab.prototype.show** you will get a fair idea how tab works in bootstrap.

Comment: So, there is no way to navigate to a tab from a different page?

Comment: Yes you can.
            $(document).ready(function () {
 //trigger the click event of  <a href="#rules" data-toggle="tab">

               
            }); it will work

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootrap doesnt do anything for you in this case. You could just insert into your page some script:

```
$(function() {
  $('.tabbable-line [href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this code for navigate tab based on url and on click update url.

```
$('.nav-tabs li [href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');

$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```